# Delay in calling class contained in dll

Tags: c#, console

Edit:  There is a long delay between calling a procedure that uses classes contained within a dll, and that procedure actually starting.  It only happens on one computer.

I've got a C# console app that parses a text file and appends its contents to an output file.  After appending, it then inserts the data into a database.  All of this works correctly.

The problem is that the process takes 35 seconds on the production computer, while it is instantaneous on my development box.  I have debug messages going to a log file, but I can't make sense of what is going on.  I suspect there's a time delay in establishing the database connection (even though pings and network checks seem to be ok), but the log file says the delay occurs between writing to the output file and starting the db procedure.  The kicker is that there's NO code between the two calls.  I think it's being delayed between log writes.  Here's the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
        bool debug = false;
        if (args.Length > 1)
            debug = args[1].ToUpper() == "DEBUG";
        if (File.Exists(args[0])) {
            if (new Parser(args[0], debug).Parse() == 0) {
                string newname = "renamed file";
                File.Move(args[0], newname);
            }
        }
    }
class Parser {
    void Log(string message) {
        Console.Out.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", DateTime.Now, message));
        Console.Out.Flush();
    }
    void LogDebug(string message) {
        if (debug) {
            Log(message);

        }
    }
    public int Parse() {
        try {
            LogDebug("Start Parse()");
            TranslateInputFile();
            WriteOutputFile();
            InsertIntoDatabase();
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log(string.Format("Could not import file {0}: {1}", InputFile, e.Message));
            return -1;
        }
    }
   void ParseInputFile() {
       LogDebug("Start ParseInputFile()");
       //snip
       LogDebug("Start ParseInputFile()"); 
}
   void WriteOutputFile() {
        LogDebug("Start WriteOutputFile()");
        try {                
            using (StreamWriter sr = new StreamWriter(OutputFile, true)) {
                //snip
                sr.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log("Error writing output file: " + e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
        LogDebug("End WriteOutputFile()");
    }
    void InsertIntoDatabase() {
        LogDebug("Start InsertIntoDatabase()");
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnStr);
        string sql = "<stuff>";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
        try {
            LogDebug("Opening Connection");
            conn.Open();
            LogDebug("Performing Insert");
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log(e.Message);
        }
        finally {
            LogDebug("Closing Connection");
            conn.Close();
        }
        LogDebug("End InsertIntoDatabase()");
    }
}
```

From the command line:

```
parser.exe temp_c.dat debug >>Parser.log 2>>&1
```

The log file shows:

```
8/10/2015 10:39:21 AM: Start Parse()
8/10/2015 10:39:21 AM: Starting TranslateInputFile()
8/10/2015 10:39:21 AM: End TranslateInputFile()
8/10/2015 10:39:22 AM: Start WriteOutputFile()
8/10/2015 10:39:22 AM: End WriteOutputFile()
8/10/2015 10:39:55 AM: Start InsertIntoDatabase()
8/10/2015 10:39:55 AM: Opening Connection
8/10/2015 10:39:56 AM: Performing Insert
8/10/2015 10:39:56 AM: Closing Connection
8/10/2015 10:39:56 AM: End InsertIntoDatabase()
8/10/2015 10:39:56 AM: End Parse()
```

The question is, where is the delay between writing to output and writing to database coming from?  The followup is, if it's actually a delay in connecting to the database, what am I doing wrong with the logging that throws off the timestamps?  As I mentioned earlier, it's instantaneous on my desktop using the same settings.  Both computers are on the same physical network and ping times to the database are <1ms.

I am using a 3rd-party database connection class (DotConnect for Oracle, from DevArt) whose dll is stored in the same directory as the console app.  We use it extensively in various apps and servers and it's never had connection problems using the same settings.

EDIT:
The comment about the antivirus got me thinking in that direction and I found some more stuff.
1) The event log shows 2 failed logins for the (disabled) guest account at the same time as the program is run.  They've been going on since I put the program in, I just never looked.
2) I moved instantiation of the OracleConnection object to the beginning of the Parse procedure and the delay moved with it.  This leads me in the direction of file system permissions on the 2 Devart dll files that contain the class.
3) I manually ran the virus checker on the output file and it was almost instantaneous.

The app runs as a scheduled job using the logged-in user's credentials, who has full control for all of that stuff.  I also ran the program manually with the same results.  Any idea why there would be login attempts from Guest while the program runs?

Edit 2: 
After more wrangling, I've discovered that the delay always comes when calling whichever procedure includes instantiating the OracleConnection object.  In several iterations, it repeatably waits 30 seconds from the time the procedure is called to the time the procedure actually starts.  I changed the title of the post to reflect that, and put a summary at the top.  I still got nothing; permissions are already set correctly and the dll loads instantly everywhere else.

Comment: Could the database library be connecting lazily: delaying the actual connection until it is used?

Comment: Or maybe the antivirus locks the written file until it has finished scanning it?

Comment: Lots of stuff happens between these two methods.  The Just-In-Time compiler runs so that InsertIntoDatabase() can execute.  One thing it has to do to get there is to load the Oracle data provider.  That is not a subtle piece of code.  It is a mixed-mode assembly with lots of unmanaged code.  Some of which is likely to execute when the DLL is loaded.  Exactly what it does is hard to guess, but plenty of opportunity for inscrutable delays of course.  The Oracle provider has been a source of trouble since Microsoft gave up trying to support it.  So it goes.

Comment: @Hans Passant I get the intent of your post but wanted to point out that I'm using DotConnect, which is 100% managed code.  I'm sure some of the same caveats might apply, but I haven't seen this behavior from any of the other applications we have that use it.